# Let child views determine size of parent view in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view/layout that need to be sized based on the contents of the children. The layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rectangle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconImageView"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:contentDescription="Icon"
            android:src="@drawable/iconplaceholder"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="Hello"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/triangle"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/triangle"
        android:rotation="180"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I would like to do is:

- List item
- Allow the view to have a max width
- Make sure that the entire text of `@+id/labelTextView` of the text view is visible in the view and allow it to grow taller if needed, but not get any wider than the max width.
- If the text is really short, the view should just be as wide as needed
- Set the size of the `@+id/iconImageView` from code and make sure that the parent view is resized accordingly

I guess I need to override onMeasure of my view, but please advice if this is the correct way. Also, how can I measure the size of a TextView given a set of constraints, like a max width?

Comment: why to use linear layouts. for this it is better to use relative layouts. they automatically adjusts according to available space, if you write it in proper way

Comment: What would be the proper way then? I don't understand how to do that when I can't use android:layout_weight="1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you would be able to set the layout_height for the parent to `wrap_content`.  This way, it sets its view to be the size it needs to be depending on the sizes of the children inside it.

Comment: Thank you! That was just perfect! So easy when you know how. :)

Comment: So true!  No problem.